# Salvar dados de varios fragments

Tags: android

Tenho um slide ( usando a lib material-intro) que tem varios fragmentos, preciso salvar os dados que estão digitados nesses edittext dos fragmentos quando eu fechar este slide, estou tentando via intent mas não estou conseguindo.

Como estou salvando no intent no fragment:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    txtnome = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_nome);
    final Usuario user = new Usuario();

    txtnome.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("nome",txtnome.getText().toString());
            validado = !txtnome.getText().toString().isEmpty();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
}
```

Como estou tentando buscar na actvity que abre depois de fechar os slides:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_INTRO) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();

            String nome = intent.getStringExtra("nome");
            String altura = intent.getStringExtra("altura");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Nome: " + nome, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Altura: " + altura, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit()
                    .putBoolean(PREF_KEY_FIRST_START, false)
                    .apply();
        } else {
```

eles retornam null

Comment: Tente usar um `sharedpreferences` para isso. Muito mais simples.

Comment: @LMaker é que eu queria salvar apenas quando terminasse os slides, mas se não tiver jeito vai de sharedpreferences mesmo